# Ng-repeat - display row data in 2 rows

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat=x in y>    {{X. row data}}   </tr>
```

first-row-data-index-0    second row partial data index1    second row remaining data index1

> how can we achieve this. I.e. display data of repeated object in 2 rows.

Say data of object.0 in first row
Data of object.1 in second row partially
Data of object.1 in third row partially

Requirement is to add an extra row inside a repeating tr. Ng-repeat-end cant b used.

Comment: Please, clarify your question. Which one is your problem? Please, add some Origin data, or a snippet with code to see what you are doing and what you expect as result.

Answer (score 0):

Your Questions is not so clear. I am assuming you need to add two tr for one repeat element. (i.e) for every X you need two rows. If that is the case you need to repeat tbody instead of tr

```
<tbody ng-repeat="x in y" >
  <tr>
    <td>{{X. row data}}</td>
    <td>{{X. row data 2}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      {{X. secondRowData}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Ng-repeat is present on a tr. At some point inside ng-repeat if a conditiin is satisfied,i want to add 2 tr for one data looped. Simply i want to add an extra tr inside ng-repeat in addition to the already looping tr